# When using pandas, how to drop a row by its values and not by its label?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, drop

I am trying to drop certain rows from a CSV file, but not by its label. I need to drop rows with certain values.

In this csv file, how would I drop every row with `categroy == Physics`?

[image: img]

Comment: `df[df['Category'].ne('Physics')]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df = df[df['Category'] != 'Physics']
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you read the CSV into a dataframe `df`, we can do:

```
filtered = df[df["Category"] != "Physics"]
```